# BigQuery report UNKNOWN_OS

Tags: android, push-notification, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Currently I am doing push notification function in my Android app. I linked the FCM project to BigQuery so I can get report about Sent Notification through FCM API. But the report shows something confusing:
6 columns: **message_id**, **instance_id**, **message_type**, **sdk_platform**, **app_name** and **ttl**
are not consistent between messages, although I sent same notifications all the time (only notification titles are different - which is not represented in this report).

Can anybody tell me why in many rows there are **UNKNOWN_OS**, **ttl = -1**, **message_type = TOPIC** and **message_id**, **instance_id**, **app_name** are empty?

Link to my report image is below.
THANKS VERY MUCH!

P/s: I test push notifications on 2 android devices

[My BigQuery report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9zPg.png)

Comment: You probably have topic subscribers that's why you see all those entries https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: I test on 2 devices so I have 2 subscribers